# Is there a way to train an Encog neural network without loading all training set in memory?

Tags: .net, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, encog

I've been using a .NET framework to train a neural network, and my data set is really large, with a large number of inputs.

I've decided to switch to Encog due to some problems with the old framework I was using, and also because Encog seems much richer and offers additional features.

My problem is that Encog loads all training data at once, into a 2D array, and this doesn't suit me since I have a very large data set. I've tried working around this, and also checked other questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31417935/1223548) but couldn't find a good answer).

I tried working with [SQLNeuralDataSet](https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/platformspecific/j2se/data/SQLNeuralDataSet.java) and other implementations that support streaming operation but they all seem to eventually load the data into memory (using MemoryDataLoader) and this doesn't solve my problem.

Is there a way I can load (and train) my network one item at a time? Or is this option not available in Encog?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I ended up copying the source code and modifying it according to my needs. Basically, it all comes down to `Process(IMLDataPair pair)` in `GradientWorker` which, according to the documentation:

> Process one training set element.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/tree/master/encog-core-cs/ML/Data) for the data sources for Encog, there are a number of options.  Look at `Buffer/BufferedMLDataSet.cs`, for example:

```
/// This class is not memory based, so very long files can be used, without
/// running out of memory. This dataset uses a Encog binary training file as a
/// buffer.
```

Comment: I've tried `BufferedMLDataSet.cs` but it didn't really solve my problem. Basically I had to loop through my data set to build a CSV file with the inputs and outputs, then convert the CSV file (which was large) to binary using `EncogUtility.ConvertCSV2Binary` then load it into a trainingSet like this: `var trainingSet = new BufferedMLDataSet(binaryFile)` and pass the trainingSet to the BackPropagation object. It would be much better if I could load the training one by one.